# C++ Methods to insert element at beginning of a linked list and at specified index

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, nodes, prepend

For a list class, I'm trying to create a method to add a node to a linked list at the beginning of the list such as `void List::prepend(const Item& it)` as well as one to insert an element at a specific index in the list: `void List::insert(const Item& it, int index)`

So I could use some help in getting started on each of these.

I have already created a method that adds on to the end of a list:

```
void List::append(const Item& it) {
    Node *nodePtr = new Node(it, NULL);
    if(mySize == 0)
    {
        myFirst = nodePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        myLast->myNext = nodePtr;
    }
    myLast = nodePtr;
    mySize++;
}
```

But these other two are not going quite as well.

In case you're wondering, I do have a typedef here:

```
typedef double Item;
```

Comment: well, so what are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you only save the last item.
You must save the First Item into myFirst.

```
Answer these questions: 
1. What happen if mySize = 1 ?
2. Where does nodePtr point next?  ( nodePtr->next)
```

For your question:

```
void List::prepend(const Item& it) {
    Node *nodePtr = new Node(it, NULL);
    if(mySize == 0)
    {
        myFirst = nodePtr;
    }
    else{
        nodePtr->next = myFirst;
        myFirst = nodePtr;
    }
    mySize++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void List::prepend(const Item& it) {
    Node *nodePtr = new Node(it, NULL);
    if(mySize == 0)
    {
        //..
    }
    else
    {
        //..
    }    
    ++mySize;
}

void List::insert(const Item& it, int index) {
    Node *nodePtr = new Node(it, NULL); 
    if(index == 0)
    {
        //..
    }
    Node *currentNode = myFirst;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    while(currentIndex < index - 1) {
        //..
    }
    // insert before
    // ..
    ++mySize;
}
```

Fill in the //.. areas yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be your function (List::append(const Item& it)) has a bit mistake that you have not yet updated the last pointer to NULL.